# Need help understanding bitmaps, bitwise operations, and C

Tags: c, architecture, bitmap, binary

#### Disclaimer: I am asking these questions in relation to an assignment. The assignment itself calls for implementing a bitmap and doing some operations with that, but that is not what I am asking about. I just want to understand the concepts so I can try the implementation for myself.

I need help understanding bitmaps/bit arrays and bitwise operations. I understand the basics of binary and how left/right shift work, but I don't know exactly how that use is beneficial.

Basically, I need to implement a bitmap to store the results of a prime sieve (of Eratosthenes.) This is a small part of a larger assignment focused on different IPC methods, but to get to that part I need to get the sieve completed first. I've never had to use bitwise operations nor have I ever learned about bitmaps, so I'm kind of on my own to learn this.

From what I can tell, bitmaps are arrays of a bit of a certain size, right? By that I mean you could have an 8-bit array or a 32-bit array (in my case, I need to find the primes for a 32-bit unsigned int, so I'd need the 32-bit array.) So if this is an array of bits, 32 of them to be specific, then we're basically talking about a string of 32 1s and 0s. How does this translate into a list of primes? I figure that one method would evaluate the binary number and save it to a new array as decimal, so all the decimal primes exist in one array, but that seems like you're using too much data.

Do I have the gist of bitmaps? Or is there something I'm missing? I've tried reading about this around the internet but I can't find a source that makes it clear enough for me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you have a list of primes: {3, 5, 7}. You can store these numbers as a character array: `char c[] = {3, 5, 7}` and this requires 3 bytes.

Instead lets use a single byte such that each set bit indicates that the number is in the set. For example, 01010100. If we can set the byte we want and later test it we can use this to store the same information in a single byte. To set it:

```
char b = 0;
// want to set `3` so shift 1 twice to the left
b = b | (1 << 2); 
// also set `5`
b = b | (1 << 4);
// and 7
b = b | (1 << 6);
```

And to test these numbers:

```
// is 3 in the map:
if (b & (1 << 2)) {
  // it is in...
```

Comment: right, only the position and the state of the bits are relevant, the actual value is a by product.

Comment: So in this instance, the binary valued converted to decimal doesn't matter? Unless I'm doing something wrong, 01010100 converts to 84 in decimal, which has nothing to do with the values 3, 5, and 7. So if that isn't important, is it only the position of the bits that matters? And if that's the case, a 32-bit number would only have 32 positions. I must be missing something.

Comment: Hmm, then how am I supposed to store the primes for a 32-bit integer? The length of such a string would be 4.29 billion chars long...

Comment: Forgive that last part, I was confusing bits and bytes. It would be 536 million chars, assuming we store 8 "numbers" per char.

Comment: that's right the basic idea behind bitmaps is this. Efficient use of them is another matter which is related to algorithms

Comment: for example, if the average distance between two set bits in a bitmap is 2000 bits, then it would make sense to use a list of numbers instead of a bitmap.

Comment: Okay, well that helps. I still feel like I'm missing something, though, because it just seems terribly inefficient. Thank you for the answers, though, they're helping a lot.

Comment: It looks like there are about 200,000,000 primes in that range, so you need around a billion bytes if you use integers

Answer (score 1):

A bitmap allows you to construct a large *predicate* function over the range of numbers you're interested in. If you just have a single 8-bit char, you can store Boolean values for each of the eight values. If you have 2 chars, it doubles your range.

So, say you have a bitmap that already has this information stored, your *test* function could look something like this:

```
bool num_in_bitmap (int num, char *bitmap, size_t sz) {
    if (num/8 >= sz) return 0;
    return (bitmap[num/8] >> (num%8)) & 1;
}
```

Comment: Okay, so 1 char = 8 Boolean values, 2 chars = 16 Boolean values ... 536 million chars = 4.29 billion Boolean values - am I getting this right so far? So my string would have to be 536 million chars long for a 32-bit integer, right? That seems enormous for such a task...

Comment: Yes. Those appear to be correct conclusions. . . . Oops. It appears that I forgot to use the `size` parameter in my example. :(

Answer (score 1):

You are going to need a lot more than 32 bits.

You want a sieve for up to 2^32 numbers, so you will need a bit for each one of those. Each bit will represent one number, and will be 0 if the number is prime and 1 if it is composite. (You can save one bit by noting that the first bit must be 2 as 1 is neither prime nor composite. It is easier to waste that one bit.)

2^32 = 4,294,967,296

Divide by 8

536,870,912 bytes, or 1/2 GB.

So you will want an array of 2^29 bytes, or 2^27 4-byte words, or whatever you decide is best, and also a method for manipulating the individual bits stored in the chars (ints) in the array.

It sounds like eventually, you are going to have several threads or processes operating on this shared memory.You may need to store it all in a file if you can't allocate all that memory to yourself.

Say you want to find the bit for x. Then let a = x / 8 and b = x - 8 * a. Then the bit is at arr[a] & (1 << b). (Avoid the modulus operator % wherever possible.)

```
//mark composite
a = x / 8;
b = x - 8 * a;
arr[a] |= 1 << b;
```

This sounds like a fun assignment!

Comment: Fun.... I wish. It probably would have been, if we were given the tools to succeed. Unfortunately, the instructor has chosen to leave out key components like this one. So for the uninitiated like myself, it becomes much more difficult and much less fun.

The results will be stored in the heap for the threaded part, and in a shared memory object in the multiple processes part. Don't even get me started on those - they haven't been discussed in class, either.

Comment: So for the heap, just allocate an array in the main function. All the pthreads will have access to it. You will need to guard it with a mutex. The code I supplied will make the threads overwrite each others' changes. Hopefully, you will have discussed shm_open() in class by the time you need it.

Comment: The assignment was due on Monday, and we haven't discussed shm_open(), at least not in class or the readings. The class isn't structured well, but it'll be over in a week. I just wish I'd have learned more...

Comment: Why do you say to avoid the modulus operator `%`? It is because it's not well-defined for negative inputs?